# CPU stuck at 99% for a few hours: figuring out logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs

extract from `syslog`:

```
CRON[pid]: (user) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -
execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
```

My CPU has been stuck at 99% for a few hours now, and I'm assuming it's because of this. Would anyone happen to know what this is, how it started and how to stop it?

EDIT: I tried `top -n1` and I see this in return multiple times:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND  
PID user      20   0     0    0    0 Z 99.9  0.0   0:00.00 fuser <defunct>
```

this line repeats about 8 times.

EDIT2:

```
uname-a:

user SMP Tue Feb 14 13:27:41 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:    11.10
Codename:   code
```

EDIT 3:

After reboot, the system went back to the same `99% cpu usage` and the same `top -n1` result.

Comment: There's a bug in that command.    The stderr output of fuser is being sent to /dev/null, as designed.  But so is the stderr output of find, which probably was not.   (Because -execdir actually doesn't launch the command via the shell, so the 2>/dev/null is being processed by the shell directly invoked by cron).   However, while this may be concealing relevant symptoms, the positioning of the 2>/dev/null is not the cause of your CPU usage.

Comment: This is very weird: a zombie process should not be using CPU time (it doesn't even have code to execute). You have either a bug in process reporting tools or in your kernel. What OS is this (version, kernel, etc.)? Is there any virtualization? What is the output of `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: The `fuser` command is probably very short lived.   It spends its time using up CPU time (system time, not user time) generating /proc data that it (trivially) consumes.   Each instance of `fuser` probably finishes very quickly.  But it is probably being run many times since there are, I suppose, many session files in there.   The 99.9% figure probably just means that that instance of `fuser` used CPU intensively before it died.  `find` probably isn't very agressive about reaping children; it will likely call `waitpid` again only when leaving a directory or running `fuser` again.

Comment: uname-a:

`user SMP Tue Feb 14 13:27:41 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

lsb_release -a:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 11.10
Release: 11.10
Codename: code

Comment: Oops, correction: for `-execdir ... \;` the wait should be immediate, since the return code is needed as the result of the predicate (I was mixing this up with `-execdir ...+` which always returns true, I think).

Comment: In the mean time, should I just reboot? Or would that prevent me from figuring out the issue?

Comment: @JamesYoungman do you think this could be happening because too many session files are there?

Comment: Testing this link out. Will update as the answer if it works. http://www.flynsarmy.com/2011/11/fuser-using-100-cpu-in-ubuntu-11-10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://www.flynsarmy.com/2011/11/fuser-using-100-cpu-in-ubuntu-11-10/

in `/etc/cron.d/php5 on Ubuntu 11.10:`

Replace
`09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] &amp;&amp; [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] &amp;&amp; find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2&gt;/dev/null \; -delete`

With
`09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] &amp;&amp; [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] &amp;&amp; find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete`

Comment: This worked, the issue seems to be solved.

Answer (score 4):

This is a cron job that cleans up old session files from  /var/lib/php5/ . If it hangs on 99% you should perhaps check out the destination folder ( /var/lib/php5/) for an excessive amount of files or perhaps even filesystem corruption.

The process is started from crontab. See the crontab listings (described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/397834/copy-cron-jobs-from-one-server-to-another-server-using-bash-prefereable/397877#397877)). You kan kill the process and remove it from crontab, but it's more likely that you have an underlying problem such as an excessive amount of files that needs to be fixed.

Comment: If you end up with multiple cleanup processes running, they may interfere with each other by generating locks on the directory when they delete files.  Try temporarily removing it from the crontab until the load clears.  Then add it with a longer interval between runs.  You may want to move it to a script with a locking mechanism to ensure only one instance is running.  Kill off any multiple instances of the command for now.